# ¿Cómo busco con "find" diferentes tipos de fichero?

Tags: bash, find

Quiero usar el comando find en un script de bash para buscar archivos del tipo file y directorios.

¿Cómo puedo especificar eso en los parámetros?

Probé algo como:

```
find "ruta" -name "" -type f -type d
```

este último no me dio error, pero no mostró nada

```
find "ruta" -name "" -type f d
find "ruta" -name "" -type f,d
```

Es un script en bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente usa una condición `-o` para que busque cosas que cumplan una de las dos condiciones:

```
find . \( -type d -o -type f \)
```

Esto es la suma de hacer `find -type f` y `find -type d`, correspondiente a tipo fichero y tipo directorio respectivamente.